# FileWriter e FileOutputStream: quando devo trabalhar com cada um deles?

Tags: java, inputstream

Muitas vezes encontramos códigos que poderiam ser resolvidos com o uso de objetos do tipo `FileWriter` ou `FileOutputStream`. Por exemplo, um código simples que escreve "`Teste`" no arquivo `/tmp/arquivo`:

Com `FileWriter`:

```
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/tmp/arquivo"););
output.write("Teste");
```

Com `FileOutputStream`:

```
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/arquivo"));
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(file));
output.write("Teste");
```

Isso acontece quando estamos lidando com caracteres (outro exemplo seria um programa que faz a cópia de conteúdo de um arquivo para outro). Quando estamos lidando com arquivos diferentes, tais como imagens, o `FileWriter` já não é apropriado. Mas quais são as implicações de usar `FileOutputStream` e `FileWriter` com fluxos de caracteres? Algum é considerado melhor que o outro neste caso? Tem diferença?

Comment: Um link interessante sobre o tema: [Escrita de arquivos em Java: FileWriter e FileOutputStream](https://ifsantos.wordpress.com/2011/09/09/escrita-de-arquivos-em-java-filewriter-e-fileoutputstream/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introdução

Conforme já se sabe, as classes `Writer` têm uma funcionalidade a mais em torno das classes `OutputStream` que é a conversão de caracteres. Quando você usa um Writer, você trabalha com String e char[], enquanto que com `OutputStream` você só pode usar byte[].

### Conversão de streams para writers

Mas se você tiver um `OutputStream` qualquer (como um `FileOutputStream`) é possível convertê-lo para um `Writer` se você usar um `OutputStreamWriter`, como você fez no exemplo da pergunta. O resultado será o mesmo.

### Qual escolher?

**new FileWriter(...)** ou **new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(...))**?

Primeiro, o que diz a documentação oficial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

Então, o FileWriter usa a codificação default e o  OutputStreamWriter permite escolher a codificação do arquivo gerado.

E, segundo o código da JDK 8, numa versão bem recente (07 de outubro de 2016),

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/141beb4d854d/src/share/classes/java/io/FileWriter.java

a implementação do **FileWriter** simplesmente herda toda a implementação de OutputStreamWriter e **apenas implementa construtores** de conveniência para os casos mais comuns.

Então, conclui-se que não há diferença entre eles quando a codificação padrão da JVM é suficiente. Pode usar então a forma mais curta, com FileWriter.

O OutputStreamWriter pode ser usado para escolher a codificação de caracteres manualmente e também tem outro uso: quando você recebe um OutputStream que não foi você que construiu e precisa convertê-lo num Writer para escrever Strings nele de forma mais conveniente.

Já para arquivos que não são de texto, obviamente, use um FileOutputStream sem convertê-lo para OutputStreamWriter.